# Why do I get Invalid date at the beginning of each month?

Tags: javascript, date, google-apps-script, coingecko

**Goal:**

Import data from coinGecko API server to Google Apps Script then send it to Google Sheets.

It imports yesterday's information from the coinGecko server.

**Issue:**

The API server returns an error, only at the beginning (end) of the month.

**Error message:**

> Jul 1, 2022, 2:40:43 AM   Error   Exception:
>
> Request failed for https://api.coingecko.com returned code 400.
> Truncated server response: {"error":"invalid date"} (use
> muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response)
> at fetchJsonObject(Code:62:36)
>
> at updateSheet(Code:45:34)
> at tryCatch(Code:38:12)
> at tryCatch(Code:41:12)
> at tryCatch(Code:41:12)
> at tryCatch(Code:41:12)
> at updateSheets(Code:4:17)
> at getImportData0(Code:7:3)

**Hypothesis:**

It should be the problem of the date object. I am using Javascript default date object. I converted it to DDMMYYYY format. But that is pretty much all I did for this date code block. I assume the root cause of this issue should be around this area, but it seems working correctly.

Should I use another date object?

**Source code:**

```
function getImportData0() {
  function updateSheets() {
    for (let i = 0; i < CoinGecko.coinSheetNames.length; i++) {
      CoinGecko.tryCatch(i);
    }
  }
  updateSheets();
}
const CoinGecko = {
  // # Entity
  serverName: 'https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/',
  endpointName: 'coins/',
  coinSheetNames: [
    { bitcoin: 'Bitcoin (BTC)' },
    { aave: 'Aave (AAVE)' },
    { aeon: 'AEON (AEON)' },
    { cardano: 'Cardano (ADA)' },
    { 'pirate-chain': 'Pirate Chain (ARRR)' },
    { dero: 'Dero (DERO)' },
    { enjincoin: 'Enjin (ENJ)' },
    { eos: 'EOS (EOS)' },
    { 'loki-network': 'Oxen (OXEN)' },
    { wownero: 'WowNero (WOW)' },
    { triton: 'Equilibria (XEQ)' },
    { haven: 'Haven (XHV)' },
    { monero: 'Monero (XMR)' },
    { ripple: 'Ripple (XRP)' },
  ],
  resourceType: 'history',
  subResourceType: ['market_data'],

  fieldTypes: ['market_cap', 'total_volume', 'current_price'],
  currency: 'usd',

  // # Main Functions
  tryCatch: function (i) {
    try {
      this.updateSheet(i);
    } catch (error) {
      CoinGecko.handleError(error);
      this.tryCatch(i);
    }
  },
  updateSheet: function (i) {
    const jsonObject = CoinGecko.fetchJsonObject(i);
    const record = CoinGecko.getRecord(jsonObject);
    CoinGecko.setRecordToSheet(record, i);
  },
  handleError: function (error) {
    if (!error.toString().includes('1015')) {
      throw error;
    }
    console.log(
      `CoinGecko server is busy. Restarting the program. [Errror Message]: ${error}`
    );
    Utilities.sleep(1000);
  },

  // # Input Boundary
  fetchJsonObject: function (i) {
    const requestUrl = this.getRequestUrl(i);
    const jsonString = UrlFetchApp.fetch(requestUrl).getContentText();
    const jsonObject = JSON.parse(jsonString);
    return jsonObject;
  },
  getRequestUrl: function (i) {
    const coinName = Object.keys(this.coinSheetNames[i]);
    return (
      this.serverName +
      this.endpointName +
      coinName +
      '/' +
      this.resourceType +
      '?date=' +
      this.getddmmyyyyYesterday()
    );
  },

  // #Interactor
  getRecord: function (jsonObject) {
    let record = [];
    this.pushDate(record);
    this.pushOtherFields(record, jsonObject);
    return record;
  },
  pushDate: function (record) {
    const date = this.getyyyymmddYesterday();
    record.push(date);
  },
  pushOtherFields: function (record, jsonObject) {
    const fieldTypes = this.fieldTypes;
    for (let i = 0; i < fieldTypes.length; i++) {
      this.pushOtherField(record, jsonObject, fieldTypes[i]);
    }
  },
  pushOtherField: function (record, jsonObject, fieldType) {
    marketData = jsonObject[this.subResourceType[0]];
    currency = this.currency;
    const value = marketData[fieldType][currency];
    record.push(value);
    return record;
  },
  getddmmyyyyYesterday() {
    return this.getYesterday('day', 'month', 'year');
  },
  getyyyymmddYesterday: function () {
    return this.getYesterday('year', 'month', 'day');
  },
  getYesterday: function (top, middle, end) {
    return (date =
      this.getYearMonthDay()[top] +
      '-' +
      this.getYearMonthDay()[middle] +
      '-' +
      this.getYearMonthDay()[end]);
  },
  getYearMonthDay: function () {
    const now = new Date();
    const yearMonthDay = {};
    yearMonthDay['year'] = now.getFullYear();
    yearMonthDay['month'] = this.getMonth(now);
    yearMonthDay['day'] = ('0' + (now.getDate() - 1)).slice(-2);
    return yearMonthDay;
  },
  getMonth: function (now) {
    const month = ( '0' + (now.getMonth() + 1))//.slice(-2)
    // ('0' + (now.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
    return month;
  },

  // # Output Boundary
  setRecordToSheet: function (record, i) {
    const sheetName = Object.values(this.coinSheetNames[i]); /* [0] */
    const range = this.getRange(record, i, sheetName);
    range.setValues([record]);
    console.log(`Importing ${sheetName} Completed`);
  },
  getSheet: function (sheetName) {
    const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    const sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
    if (sheet == null) {
      throw new Error(
        `'${sheetName}' sheet is not found in this Spreadsheet. Please fix the sheet name or create a new sheet.`
      );
    }
    return sheet;
  },
  getRange: function (record, i, sheetName) {
    const sheet = this.getSheet(sheetName);

    let lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
    if (lastRow == null) {
      lastRow = 1;
    }
    const colRow = record.length;
    const range = sheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 1, 1, colRow);
    return range;
  },
};
```

Comment: `console.log()` the date that causes the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer:** Change your `getYearMonthDay()` function to this:

```
  getYearMonthDay: function () {
    var now = new Date();
    now.setDate(now.getDate()-1)
    const yearMonthDay = {};
    yearMonthDay['year'] = now.getFullYear();
    yearMonthDay['month'] = this.getMonth(now);
    yearMonthDay['day'] = ('0' + now.getDate()).slice(-2);
    return yearMonthDay;
  }
```

**Long answer:** There's a bug in your code when calculating yesterday's date. You're just subtracting 1 from `now.getDate()`, which just returns [an integer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDate), when you should instead subtract 1 from the `now` object, which is a `Date`.

Here's a way to check it out by yourself. I added a `console.log(yearMonthDay)` to see what it generates, and I set the `Date` object to the beginning of the month using `const now = new Date("July 1, 2022")`;

```
    function getYearMonthDay() {
        const now = new Date("July 1, 2022");
        const yearMonthDay = {};
        yearMonthDay['year'] = now.getFullYear();
        yearMonthDay['month'] = this.getMonth(now);
        yearMonthDay['day'] = ('0' + (now.getDate() - 1)).slice(-2);
        console.log(yearMonthDay)
        return yearMonthDay;
    }
```

The output is this:

```
    { year: 2022, month: '07', day: '00' }
```

A day 00 is certainly an invalid date. You can just use [`setDate()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setDate) on the original `Date` object and subtract 1 (change it to a variable or create a new one if you want to keep it as constant).

```
function getYearMonthDay() {
    var now = new Date("July 1, 2022");
    now.setDate(now.getDate()-1) //turns into yesterday
    const yearMonthDay = {};
    yearMonthDay['year'] = now.getFullYear();
    yearMonthDay['month'] = this.getMonth(now);
    yearMonthDay['day'] = ('0' + now.getDate()).slice(-2);
    console.log(yearMonthDay)
    return yearMonthDay;
}
```

Here the output is as it should be:

```
    { year: 2022, month: '06', day: '30' }
```